# How to find all strings that match to an input query of one or more words

Tags: python, string

I'm currently working with a JSON file that has a number of theater locations stored in it as well as the code that corresponds to each location.

What I'm currently doing is, if a user enters in a location, I return the respective code. 
What I would like to do instead is, I want to split the input string and search for the respective keywords in my JSON file and return the appropriate location matches and their codes.

This is my code so far:

```
queryname = input("Enter the Venue Name:")

def query():
    for d in data['BookMyShow']['arrVenues']:
        if d['VenueName'] == queryname:
            yield d['VenueCode']

f1 = query()
for f in f1:
    print(f)
```

I'm going to change my input() statement into a input.split() so I can store the individual keywords. However I'm not sure how to change my function so as to search for each of these individual keywords and return the relevant strings.

So, an example would be something like this:

```
Enter the Venue Name:
Carnival
```

> My file contains 3 instances of Carnival (Carnival Bangalore, Carnival Mumbai and Carnival Delhi)

The output I want it to return is this:

```
Carnival Bangalore A000
Carnival Mumbai A001
Carnival Delhi A002
```

This is what a snippet of my data file looks like:

```
{
  "BookMyShow": {
    "arrVenues": [
      {
          "VenueCode": "AAAD",
          "VenueName": "Khinvasara Cineplex (Apsara Cinema): Aurangabad",
          "VenueSeq": "9999"
      },
      {
         "VenueCode": "AACM",
         "VenueName": "Anjana Chitra Mandir: Raniganj",
         "VenueSeq": "9999"
      },
      {
         "VenueCode": "AAME",
         "VenueName": "Shree Ram Cinema: Deesa",
         "VenueSeq": "9999"
      },
      {
        "VenueCode": "AASH",
        "VenueName": "Adarsh Chitra Mandir: Bhandara",
        "VenueSeq": "9999"
      },
      {
        "VenueCode": "ABCC",
        "VenueName": "Abhay Cinema: Chandrapur",
        "VenueSeq": "9999"
      }]
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your `data` look like? Can you post a snippet?

Comment: Post a sample of your `data`

Comment: Yes, of course, hold on a sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another loop  and use the `in` operator:

```
def query():
    keywords = queryname.split(' ')
    for d in data['BookMyShow']['arrVenues']:
        for keyword in keywords:
            if(keyword in d['VenueName']):
                yield(d) # you should yield the whole venue because you want to print both the venue code and name later on
                break # this is so that we don't yield it twice when multiple keywords match
```

To print out the venues in the format you showed, you can do this:

```
f1 = query()
for f in f1:
    print(f['VenueName'], f['VenueCode'])
```

For case-insensitive-ness, just convert both sides to lowercase/uppercase:

```
if keyword.lower() in d['VenueName'].lower():
```

If you want to only match venues that contain all keywords use this:

```
def query():
    keywords = queryname.split(' ')
    for d in data['BookMyShow']['arrVenues']:
        reject = False
        for keyword in keywords:
            if not (keyword.lower() in d['VenueName'].lower()):
                reject = True
                break
        if not reject:
            yield d
```

Comment: Is this all he needs? Just use the `in` operator to search a string? I guess it was trivial.

Comment: @Sweeper, this works great! Thank you :) I was wondering if there was a way I could make the search case insensitive? But, I guess I'll have to use regex for that huh?

Comment: @Teju_M you could use `.lower()`

Comment: Thanks so much @Sweeper, I didn't realize the solution could be simple like that. Here I was annoyed I'd have to use regex :P

Comment: @Sweeper, do you think there's a way I can change it so it finds only the relevant keywords. Cause if I type in 'Chitra Mandir' for example, it returns all results that contain either Chitra or Mandir and I would like it to filter only strings that contained both words.

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper I deeply appreciate the help